# Redirect to a function in Django from template on select tag using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, templates

I have a select statement like this in Django template:

```
<select onchange="change_session()" name="select_path" id="select_path">
            {% for i in session_info %}
              <option name="server_id" id="select_path" value="{{ i.id }}">{{ i.session_name }}</option>
               {% endfor %}
            </select>
```

When the user selects another option I want to redirect to a view called `change_user` in Django. I want to do this simply like I do in the form. For that I tried to write a Javascript function called change_session which redirects to a view when the user change the option. I want to pass the value of id `change_session_id` to the Django view. Here' what I have so far:

```
function change_session() {
    var session_id=document.getElementById('select_path').value;

}
```

How do I modify this function to pass to a Django view called `change_session`. Thank you

Comment: First get your javascript right, then show us what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect it using only the `<select>`

```
<select name="select_path" id="select_path"
    ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    {% for i in session_info %}
    <option value="{% url app_name:change_user i.id %}">{{ i.session_name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

just change the option value, I don't know the exact url.

Comment: This is not what I want. I want to redirect to a view along with the value.